# Convex Constraint on Sine Wave Simularity

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

So lets say you have a vector X = [x1 x2 x3 ..... xn]

You want to optimize a cost function over X.

However you want to constrain the vector X to look like a sine wave.  Say you can parameterize a sine wave using a vector θ.  Ideally then, I would like to have X look like a sine wave that belongs to the family of sine waves that is enclosed by:

(θ - e) < X < (θ + e)  where e is some error margin.

My question is then, is there someway to formulate a constraint that a vector "looks similar" to a give sine wave?

Comment: Sure, $\|X-\theta\|_\infty \leq e$. Done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael!  I'm honored to have the CVX man himself.  I am actually using CVX in matlab to solve this problem.  I was wondering if I could ask you one more question while you are here?

I have this situation:

minimize (norm(y-cos(w*t+p),1)

This is basically given a vector y, vector t, and constant w, minimize the 1-norm of (y-cos(w*t+p)) over the vector p.

Now, if my understanding is correct this is only a globally convex problem if you restrict the domain of p to say 0->pi.

So my question is how can I incorporate a sin/cos type function into my objective function?

Comment: Sorry, it cannot be done. See the FAQ on http://ask.cvxr.com ... Even if you could add a cos function the larger expression is not convex.